# Firestore index issue?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple query in Flutter, pulling data from Firestore. I added an .orderBy() clause, and the whole thing breaks.

```
"The query requires an index."
```

Here is the code:

```
   final querySnapshot = await _firestore
        .collection('Reviews')
        .where("document_id", isEqualTo: widget.documentID)
        .where("is_deleted", isEqualTo: false)
        .orderBy('posted_on')
        .get()
        .catchError((e) => print("error fetching data: $e"));
```

Ok, so I make an index (see screenshot below), but it STILL won't work?

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the stack trace? Errors in the console.

Comment: Did you try `.orderBy('posted_on', descending: true)` ?